# Database technique for editing records and ensuring record is not updated until the record is approved

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, structure, relational

How would you handle a situation with the following scenario?

You have a table with customer records with the following fields:

```
id, name, email, phone
1, John, john@example.com, 515-222-3333
2, Smith, smith@example.com, 515-333-444
```

John opens his record and changes his phone number. However, the actual record of the customer should not be changed until the admin approves the change.

How would you handle a situation like this?

Would you?

```
a. Create an exact replica of customer table called customer-temp
b. Copy the record of John into customer-temp
c. let the admin review the updated record in customer-temp
d. once approved, the record is replaced with the record of john in customer table and remove John's record from customer-temp
```

Is this the best solution or is there a better way to handle this? Also what if customer table has a few other tables in relations?

Expert advise would be appreciated. FYI, i use Postgresql database.

----- updated format ---

Answer (score 0):

I would have an additional attribute for each attribute that needs review.

In your example, the entries could be:

```
id, name, name_tmp, email, email_tmp, phone, phone_tmp
```

`name` would contain the approved name, `name_tmp` the name that has been edited by the user.
Upon approval, the contents of `name_tmp` are copied to `name`.

That way you don't have any problems with foreign key relationships.

If you really don't want the attributes in the main table, create a `customer_temp` table like you suggested with `id` as primary key and foreign key referencing `customer`. The downside is that you need more joins in your queries that way.